# How to restart an activity which called some other class using Context?

Tags: android, android-activity

When i am in an Activity say Activity_A, i go to a class_B using the context of Activity_A.

Now when i want to restart the Activity_A from the class_B. I use this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, Activity_A.class);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

what i want is when i am calling the class_B from various Activities, it must restart the Activity it is called from, using the context which is sent to the class_B from the Activity.

i want to replace Activity_A.class with the Activity which called class_B

Comment: What does it mean "go to a class B"?

Comment: like calling a method of class_B which asks for the current Activity context as parameter

Comment: You cannot restart the parent activity from the child activity, but yes, you can startActivityForResult(Intent, int), and do your job  once the Acitivty B is finished.

Comment: i want to have a method in some class. Any activity which calls this method must be restarted. Cant this be done??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case you shoud pass a class variable togethe with Context of activity.
e.g. from Actitity_A:

```
class_B.doMethod(this,Activity_A.class);
```

And use class variable for start Activity from class_B

Answer (score 0):

what about using startActivityForResult(intent,code) instead of just startActivity(intent)
I think this may work

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a string containing name of the Activity. like below

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, Activity_A.class);
intent.putExtra("CALLED_FROM","ACTIVITY_A"); //PASSING FLAG Variable to know from where it called
context.startActivity(intent);
```

'

in onCreate of Activity_B  you can use below code.

```
String calledFrom = getIntent().getStringExtra("CALLED_FROM");
```

and from ClassB, you can basically check Activity Names in calledFrom String and start Activity Accordingly.